# Why is my Logback logger not getting logged in the root logger?

Tags: java, logback, logback-classic

OK, I only have one appender configured:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>%d{yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

then a root level:

```
<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
```

if I define a logger like this:

```
<logger name="com.mypackage.etc" level="trace" additivity="true">
```

it doesn't work, nothing comes up in the log unless I change the root level.

If I do this it works:

```
<logger name="com.mypackage.etc" level="trace" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</logger>
```

I don't understand why I have to manually specify the appender-ref everywhere, I just want the trace level to be logged in the same appender as defined in root.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've created a logback-spring.xml in a sample springboot application containing only the appender you defined, the root level the same as you defined, and the logger <logger name="com.mypackage.etc" level="trace" additivity="true"> and trace logs are printed on the console. There's maybe something else in your configuration which we are missing out